# Best books to teach undergraduate engineering students and for interview.

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I am looking for jobs in the educational field (engineering). I am from mathematics background. I want to prepare well for the interview, and if selected I want to teach the engineering students in the simplest way with the history of the origin of the subject. Or what particular subject means? Since I was also a student, I never went into the depth of the subject. But I don't want the same for interviews and teaching. Kindly suggest some links, books or any methods help me in this case. It will mean a lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard a lot of praise about *[Concepts of Modern Mathematics by I.Stewart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CWR4MIK)*, I believe it's worth checking out.